# NiFi ListSFTP connector cannot connect to sftp server

Tags: authentication, apache-nifi

I have problems getting ListSFTP processor to work.

First I have tested accessing the sftp server using the commandline on the NiFi server. This works but I have to provide the pass phrase of the private ssh key file.

Then I made sure that I configured the ListSFTP processor using the same settings as the sftp commandline:

- Hostname: ip address of the server
- Port: 22
- Username: Username with access to the server and bound to the key
- Private Key Path: set to the full path of the file containing
- Private Key Phrase: password for the key file
- Remote path: .
- Strict Host Key Checking: false
- Host Key File: File hat contains the output of ssh-keyscan for the
  given server

With these settings I get an error in the logfile. Any idea why NiFi cannot access the key file and access the sftp server. Cheers

> 2020-03-19 15:43:19,736 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP
>   ListSFTP[id=d343fa19-0170-1000-3352-999829a448cc] Failed to perform
>   listing on remote host due to java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain c
>   onnection to remote host due to com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid
>   privatekey: [B@6d9b662: {} java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain
>   connection to remote host due to com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:
>   invalid privatekey: [B@6d9b662
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.getChannel(SFTPTransfer.java:515)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.getListing(SFTPTransfer.java:212)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.getListing(SFTPTransfer.java:175)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFileTransfer.performListing(ListFileTransfer.java:106)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP.performListing(ListSFTP.java:146)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.list.AbstractListProcessor.listByTrackingTimestamps(AbstractListProcessor.java:472)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.list.AbstractListProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractListProcessor.java:414)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>           at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@6d9b662
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:388)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.getChannel(SFTPTransfer.java:485)
>           ... 18 common frames omitted

Comment: what version of nifi?

Comment: Version 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does the version matter? We can update to 1.11 if necessary.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but there was an issue with the JSch library used by NiFi not supporting some newer key types, and we switched to a new library starting in 1.11.0, so it might be worth trying 1.11.4 that just got released yesterday

Comment: Hi Bryan, I managed to get it working. It turned out that the JSch library cannot handle the newer format that the ssh-keygen that comes with Git for Windows produces. After some digging I discovered that ssh-keygen can convert the private key to the older format using the command: 

ssh-keygen -p -f file -m pem -P passphrase -N passphrase

This did the trick and now all's fine. 

From your comment I understand that this problem should be solved using the 1.11. version of NiFi? It is on the todo list so this problem will be gone then.

Thanks for thinking with us. Cheers